# How to download a file using php, Provided path is known

Tags: php, curl

I've to download the pdf files related to the data from the web source. I know the full path of the file. I've tried with curl but it is taking long time and writing a 0 byte file.

```
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if(file_exists($fullpath)){
    unlink($fullpath);
}
$fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Or with this (if fopen wrappers are set up in your PHP conf):

```
$file = 'http://somehosted.com/file.pdf'; // URL to the file

$contents = file_get_contents($file); // read the remote file

touch('somelocal.pdf'); // create a local EMPTY copy

file_put_contents('somelocal.pdf', $contents); // put the fetchted data into the newly created file

// done :)
```

And this one might fit you the best: http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing what your code looks like and where you might be going wrong, but take a look at this and see if there's anything that stands out as something you might have overlooked:

http://davidwalsh.name/download-urls-content-php-curl